# Save log file as Image in camera roll

Tags: c#, image-processing, windows-phone-8

I have a log file in WP8 which I wanted to save as image in camera roll so that client should be easily mail that to me and later I will again convert that to text log file.

This kind of functionality I have seen in Lync app of WP8.

I tried this but I don't this is right approach.

```
string logdata = Logger.GetLogFile();
System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
byte[] byteData = encoding.GetBytes(logdata);
MediaLibrary ml = new MediaLibrary();
ml.SavePicture("image.png", byteData);
```

Can anyone help with this.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you send the log in plain text directly?

Comment: I don't want user to see that and more over it will reveal my logic of implementing app. I can even encrypt and send, but what if internet connectivity was not there.

Why I want this functionality is even if internet connectivity not there, user can take image to laptop and send from there.

Comment: My 2 cents: if you use the EmailComposeTask API, in case of no internet connectivity, the mail is placed in the "waiting to send" folder and will be **automatically** sent when the connectivity returns. Asking the user to send an image requires more effort from the user IMHO.

Comment: Thanks @OlivierPayen I know that it will be in queue for next internet connectivity to be sent automatically. That is my last choice to encrypt and send in mail.

What about this, can the above is possible. Lync is doing that.

Comment: Bad design.  I wouldn't allow an app to send data off my phone without letting me know what's in it.

Comment: @Will let me tell you should know that it not at all possible to send data without user knowledge. Its great design thats why even microsoft implemented in their own product. Here user gone send logs himself.

Comment: @sunder: Except you're trying to obfuscate the logs you're sending.  "I don't want user to see that and more over it will reveal my logic of implementing app."  Nope.

Comment: @Will thats why I want to save it as image, which is great solution and thats why I posted question here.

Comment: @sunder: One last time.  It's a bad design because you are not allowing users to know exactly *exactly* **exactly** what you are sending to yourself from my phone.  Perhaps you don't understand that any scumbag could take my contact list, encrypt/encode it into a form that I can't read, then ask me to email it off.  I wouldn't do it, as I can't tell what the data is that I'm sending.  You can *say* it's just a log file, but why should I believe you?  You don't trust me to let me see that information, why should I trust you not to be a liar?

Comment: Thanks @Will. Let's focus on main topic the above question. Do anyone have any information regarding that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that the data you try to save using `MediaLibrary.SavePicture` is **not** a picture.

If you want to embed encrypted data within an image, you'll have to use [Steganography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography) techniques. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4877/Steganography-Hiding-messages-in-the-Noise-of-a-Pi) is an article that shows how to [Hide messages in the noise of a picture](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4877/Steganography-Hiding-messages-in-the-Noise-of-a-Pi) in C#.

Comment: I don't want to save it as encrypted data. I want similar like lync. Saving a text log file as an image. And more over I want to do that in WP8 normal .NET Framework library classes are not available in WP8.

Comment: You said "I don't want user to see that and more over it will reveal my logic of implementing app.". What does that mean then? You don't want to reveal your logic but you don't want to encrypt it? I don't understand.